# Getting unexpected error using decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, nonetype

I am trying to write a code which will allow person to enter a sentence, after which the sentence will be checked for vowels and censorship, it should also return total amount of vowels found in sentence. Here's what I have so far, however instead of running input once, I get it several times and then code comes up with following error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

```
def vowel(func):
  def wrapper():
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    vowel_count = 0
    for items in func():
        if items in vowels:
            vowel_count += 1
            print("Vowel found: " + items)
    print("Total amount of vowels", vowel_count)
    return wrapper


def censorship(func):
    def wrapper():
        censorship_list = ["Word", "Word1", "Word2", "Word3"]
        for words in censorship_list:
            if words in func():
                print("You are not allowed to use those word(s) in set order: ", words)
    return wrapper


@vowel
@censorship
def sentence():
    sent = input("Input your sentence: ")
    return sent

sentence()
```

Comment: The first one looks like it is indented in the wrong way. Can you please provide the relevant parts of the traceback (what line is not working?)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It was just pasting issue, it should be fixed now. However, I am getting error on those lines:
line 28, in <module>
    sentence()
line 5, in wrapper
    for items in func():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Your `wrapper` of the `censorship` decorator does *not* return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. First, none of the `wrapper` functions are returning a value. Thus, when `sentence` is called, the first `wrapper`, in `censorship`, will not return the necessary values to use in `vowel`. Second, the `func` call in `vowel` will return all values from the previous decorator return (in `censorship`); however, even if `wrapper` in `censorship` returned a value, it would have to also include a copy of the original string input:

```
def vowel(func):
  def wrapper():
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    vowel_count = 0
    start_val = func()
    for items in start_val:
      if items in vowels:
        vowel_count += 1
    return start_val, vowel_count
  return wrapper

def censorship(func):
  def wrapper():
     censorship_list = ["Word", "Word1", "Word2", "Word3"]
     string = func()
     for words in censorship_list:
       if words in string:
         raise ValueError("You are not allowed to use those word(s) in set order: ")
     return string
  return wrapper

@vowel
@censorship
def sentence():
  sent = input("Input your sentence: ")
  return sent
```